# Problem with the auto-dismiss of dialog in setOnLongClickListener

Tags: android, android-studio, android-recyclerview, dialog, gesture

I have problem with setOnLongClickListener. When I use this method I want the dialog, which will open, to automatically close by itself (which the method's return false should do) when I take my finger off the screen. Is it possible to do this with this method, or are there other suitable methods?

**Create Dialog**

```
protected void showDialogLongClick(final int position){

        final Dialog dialog = new Dialog(activity);
        dialog.setCancelable(true);

        View v  = activity.getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.onlongclick_card_mygift,null);
        dialog.setContentView(v);
        dialog.getWindow().setBackgroundDrawable(new ColorDrawable(Color.TRANSPARENT));

        nameLong = v.findViewById(R.id.name_longclick);
        descriptionLong = v.findViewById(R.id.gift_description);
        addressLong = v.findViewById(R.id.gift_address);
        imageCategory = v.findViewById(R.id.small_category);

        nameLong.setText(myGift.get(position).getName());
        descriptionLong.setText(myGift.get(position).getDescription());
        addressLong.setText(myGift.get(position).getAddress());
        String cat = myGift.get(position).getCategory();
        changeCategoryImage(cat, imageCategory);

        dialog.show();

    }
```

**Listener**

```
holder.card.setOnLongClickListener(new View.OnLongClickListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onLongClick(View v) {

                showDialogLongClick(position);

                return false;
            }
        });
```

**XML card dialog**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.cardview.widget.CardView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    app:cardCornerRadius="10dp">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@drawable/background_card_mygift"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:padding="10dp">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="horizontal">

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/name_longclick"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text=""
                android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
                android:textSize="25sp"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:layout_marginEnd="10dp"/>

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/small_category"
                android:layout_weight="0"
                android:layout_width="50dp"
                android:layout_height="50dp"
                android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"/>

        </LinearLayout>

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text=""
            android:textColor="#F44336"
            android:textSize="22sp"/>

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/gift_description"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text=""
            android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
            android:textSize="20sp"/>

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text=""
            android:textColor="#F44336"
            android:textSize="22sp"/>

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/gift_address"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text=""
            android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
            android:textSize="20sp"/>


    </LinearLayout>



</androidx.cardview.widget.CardView>
```

Comment: So you want to show the dialog on a long click, keep it displayed while the user is still touching the screen from that initial long click, and dismiss the dialog when the user stops touching the screen? Do I understand this correctly?

Comment: @SammyT yes, it's correct

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
view.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
            if (event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_UP) {
                //Dismiss the dialog
            }
            return false;
        }
    });

view.setOnLongClickListener(new View.OnLongClickListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onLongClick(View view) {
            //Create the dialog
            return true;
        }
    });
```

Use setOnLongClickListener for creating the dialog and use setOnTouchListener for dismissing the dialog.

So you should add setOnTouchListener to the view. Call dialog.dismiss() when MotionEvent action is MotionEvent.[ACTION_UP](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/MotionEvent#ACTION_UP) (user lifts his finger).

If the view is inside a scroll view the views onTouchListener does not get called. A simple solution is to add an onTouchListener to the scroll view and dismiss the dialog when user lifts his finger.

```
scrollView.setOnTouchListener( new View.OnTouchListener(){
        @Override
        public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
            if (event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_UP) {
                //Dismiss the dialog
                return true;
            }
            return false;
        }
    });
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, it works correctly. Did you know how to disable the scrollview that I have in the view under the dialog? When I use longClick and if I swipe up or down, the scrollview that is under continue to work and when I lift finger dialog doesn't dismiss (and i need to click out of dialog for dismiss it).

Comment: Yes. Just add the same onTouchListener to the scrollView and dismiss the dialog when user lifts his finger. I added some code above!